# I want to get call back of native permission popup call back

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I want to get the call back of a native permission popup the first time the user logs into the game and the game asks for permission.
I want to check if the user clicked on allow or deny.

[image: as in image]

Comment: What have you tried ? Share your code.
Also add inline image, not as link please

Comment: when we try to use Playgames leaderboard for the first time it shows an popup is shown in image. i want to get call backs that user allows or deny that

Comment: like in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYGj.jpg